# Good Poker AUDIO Books

Tags: texas-hold-em, books

I am looking to do more walking in order to increase my cardio. I usually listen to books on Audible (MP3) when I walk. By nature, most poker books involve charts and graphics (and that's OK). So I'm wondering if anyone has had a good experience with *listening* to a poker book instead of reading it? Are there good poker books out there that lend themselves well to the audio format?

Comment: don't know about audio, but i have read a dozen or so poker books on no limit holdem in the last month. if you are a beginner, listen to http://www.amazon.com/Getting-Started-Hold-em-Miller/dp/1880685345

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried any full-length books, but the [Thinking Poker podcast](http://www.thinkingpoker.net/category/podcast/) is a great source of poker strategy in audio format.  They always have a good strategy segment in their weekly podcast, and they have two larger for-sale offerings of longer and more in-depth strategy that are high quality.  They're at http://www.nitcast.com/collections/all.

Their podcasts are mostly non-strategy, but always have interesting poker-related content which might not directly help your game, but it'll likely make you think and smile and laugh a few times each listen.

Comment: This is great! Podcast suggestions are very much welcome too, in addition to book recommendations!

Comment: Glad to help.  There's two years of archived episodes, too, which will help occupy your time on the track.  Good luck!

Comment: Does anyone listen to Jonathan Little on Podcast?

Answer (score 2):

Decide to Play Great Poker by Annie Duke and John Vorhaus is excellent, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend:

http://haseebq.com/category/philosophy-of-poker/

and the site in general.

Answer (score 1):

Elements of Poker by Tommy Angelo was very enjoyable. As with all good books, they can be "read" more than once. He narrates it himself.

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to be off-topic here, but audiobooks are not the best option to listen no matter what is your goal.

I highly suggest picking one of the poker podcasts where you can get fresh and up to date information and actually have so good time :)

Comment: What's your reasoning why audiobooks aren't a good option? What podcasts would you recommend?

Comment: I had in mind poker audiobooks, and think it is not really worth the time since you will hardly remember the math or strategy advice, and there is not so much entertainment value in it.

While podcasts can offer both :) my hands-down favorite is Elliot Roe The Mindset Advantage, he has mentioned this in his interview https://www.mypokercoaching.com/elliot-roe-interview-poker-habits/ 

Also, pokernews has "Top pair" talking about home games and a couple of other good options, so it all depends on what you are looking for.

Comment: I appreciate that *you* might not think its worth the time, and that *you* might not remember the maths or strategy advice, or even be entertained by the format, but who can say if someone else would be? I'm just saying, I don't think your assessment can be accurate in those respects, because we just don't know. Regardless, thanks for the podcast recommendations.

Comment: Yea, that is my opinion ;) I am not saying it is true for everyone, but I surely found more value in podcasts than in audiobooks myself.